# Question about linear maps between two finite dimensional vectorspaces - matrices with three bases

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have already posted a similar question earlier, however I think that it was not quite clear where actually the issue is therefore I am trying to rephrase the problem and hope somebody can help me with that.

So we already know that if $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces and if $B$ is a basis of $V$, then given a family of vectors $(w)_B$ in $W$ that assigns every vector of $B$ a vector in $W$, the map $A(v)=A(\sum_{b\in B_v}c_v(b)b)=\sum_{b\in B_v}c_v(b)w_b$ is linear. We have already proved earlier that every vector $v$ can be described as a unique linear combination of a finite subset of basis vectors $B_v$ and their respective coordinates or scalars $c_v$ (it is a map that assigns every vector of $B_v$ a nonzero scalar/coordinate). Also a linear map is uniquely determined by the values of its basis vectors.

> To summarize:
>
> A map $A:V\rightarrow W$ with this template: $A(v)=A(\sum_{b\in B_v}c_v(b)b)=\sum_{b\in B_v}c_v(b)w_b$ is linear.
>
> And if $\tilde{A}$ is linear and $\forall_{b\in B}\tilde{A}(b)=A(b)=w_b$ then $\tilde{A}=A$

We will use this Lemma above to prove a characterization for linear maps between two finite dimensional vector spaces:

Let $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ and $\{c_1,...,c_m\}$ be a basis for $W$.

If we pick some linear map $A$ between $V$ and $W$ and define $\forall_{i\in \{1,..,n\}}A(b_i)=w_i$, then we can write each $w_i$ as a linear combination of $\{c_1,...,c_m\}$ such that we have a unique family $(a_{ji})_{j\in\{1,...,m\}\times i\in\{1,...,n\}}$ with $\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ji}c_j=w_i \forall_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}$.

We now look at a map $\tilde{A}:V\rightarrow W$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_iw_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ji}c_j)\overset{\text{DIST}}{=}\sum_{j=1}^{m}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ia_{ji})c_j=\tilde{A}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i b_i)=\tilde{A}(v)$

We conclude that $\tilde{A}$ is linear (see yellow box), i.e. the map that assigns $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i b_i$  the vector $\sum_{j=1}^{m}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ia_{ji})c_j$ is linear because it Matches the template.

Furthermore because $\tilde{A}(b_i)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ji}c_j=w_i \forall_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}$. We conclude because of the second Statement in the yellow box that $A=\tilde{A}$. Because it is 1. linear and 2. the images of the basisvecors match up.

**Now I want to ask my actual Question:**

*I want to ask if my thoughts below are correct or if there is a flaw in it and I also want to know how my possibly correct result can be interpretated.*

Given a linear map between two finite dimensional vectorspaces $(\dim V=n,\dim W=m)$, $A:V\rightarrow W$ and a fixed Basis $Q$ of $V$, if we find a map $B:V\rightarrow W$ such that $B$ is linear and $B(q)=A(q),\forall q\in Q$ then $A$ and $B$ must be equal (yellow box result 2).

We take two Basis of $W$, $C_1=\{c_1,...,c_m\}$ and $C_2=\{c'_1,...,c'_m\}$ and suppose that the Dimension of $V$ is $=n\geq2$ and even.

First similary to the discussion above we can say: $w_q=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{qj}c_j=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a'_{qj}c'_j$.

What I observed was that if we suppose that $\dim Q = n$ is even then we can describe the first half of the $w_q$ with the Basis $C_1$ and the other half with the Basis $C_2$

But what would that mean how one can interpretate the result that we can describe a linear map not with one Basis for V and one Basis for W like we did before but with one Basis for V and 2 bases for W? So in total 3 bases?

I know that the first result above motivates the Notion of a Matrix where the Family $(a_{ji})$ describe the entries.

If the result in my quetion would be Right , i.e. $A=B$ then one would have two families $(a_{qj})_{q\in\{1,...,n/2\}\times j\in\{1,...,m\}}$ and $(a'_{qj})_{q\in\{n/2+1,...,n\}\times j\in\{1,...,m\}}$. We could write a Matrix with corresponding entries the top half would be entries associated with the Basis $C_1$ and the second half below would be associated with $C_2$, but I am not really sure. What do you think about it?

But first we would have to prove the result and find a fitting linear map $B$ such that $A=B$:

$\tag{PROOF}$

Let $Q=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$

$\sum_{q=1}^{n}\lambda_qw_q=\sum_{q=1}^{n/2}\lambda_qw_q+\sum_{q=n/2+1}^{n}\lambda_qw_q=\sum_{q=1}^{n/2}\lambda_q(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{qj}c_j)+\sum_{q=n/2+1}^{n}\lambda_q(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a'_{qj}c'_j)=B(\sum_{q=1}^{n}\lambda_qb_q)=B(v)$

The map that assigns to $v=\sum_{q=1}^{n}\lambda_qb_q$, the vector $\sum_{q=1}^{n/2}\lambda_q(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{qj}c_j)+\sum_{q=n/2+1}^{n}\lambda_q(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a'_{qj}c'_j)$ is linear (yellow box first result). Therefore $B$ is linear and because $A(q)=B(q),\forall q\in Q$ we also know $A=B$ which would complete the proof.

Comment: The first part is correct. I'm not sure I get the second part. Do you want to *split up* a basis of $n=2k$ elements to two sets with $k$ elements? If yes, then you should check out **block matrices**.

Comment: Yes kind of, we have said that a linear map is uniquel determined by the values of the basisvectors of the domain-room. So I take a Basis $B$ of $V$ with $n=2k$ Elements. Then I look at the set $S=\{A(b):b\in B\}$, this set contains $n$ Elements (we also distinguish between basevectors who might have the same image) AND UNIQUELY determines the linear map $A$. And then yes I split $S$ in two disjoint sets ($S',S''$) with $k$ Elements respectively. I describe the first set with one Basis of $W$ and the other set with another Basis of $W$. I have proved see (PROOF) that the map that first (cont)

Comment: (cont) decomposes a Vector $v$ in its components in respect of Basis $B$ and then assigns a value which depends on whether the Image of the components are either in $S'$ or not in $S''$ and is a concatenation of linearcombinations of basisvectors of the first Basis of $W=C$ or the second Basis of $W=C'$ that I have determined beforehand, is a charachterization of the linear map $A$, is this what you meant with *splitting up*?

Comment: I'm still not sure we're talking about the same thing. I guess what confuses me, is that neither $C$ nor $C'$ is a basis of $W$ in general, they are just the images of $S$ and $S'$, correct?

Comment: Here is my notation, maybe this will resolve the possible missunderstanding. We have a linear map, $A:V\rightarrow W$, $V$ and $W$ are vectorspaces. I also know that $\dim V=n=2k$, I choose a Basis of $V$ and call it $B$ (it has $n$ Elements because of the Dimension of $V$). I also know that the Dimension of $W$ is $=m$, (the only Thing important here is that it is finite). I pick two bases of $W$ and call them $C,C'$. I look at the set $S=\{A(b),b\in B\}$, to be more precise $S=\{(A(b),b),b\in B\}$ to make sure that we can distinguish between each immage of the basisvecor. $S$ has $n$

Comment: Elements. I splitt up $S$ in $S'$ and $S''$ with each $k$ Elements. I describe $S'$ with $C$ and $S''$ with $C'$, with describe I mean that I assign to each element of $S'$ or $S''$ a linear combination of the basisvectors of $C$, $C'$ respectively, to answer your Question: No $C$ and $C'$ ARE bases of $W$ we have defined them as such and with $S$ and $S'$ you probably meant $S'$ and $S''$, they are already the imagesets which put together create the imageset of all the basevectors in $B$

Comment: Ok. So, basically we have an isomorphism $V\cong V_1\oplus V_2$ (by splitting up the basis), an isomorphism (or automorphism as you presented) $W\cong W'$(corresponding to the change of bases $C\leadsto C'$), and linear maps $V_1\to W$ and $V_2\to W'$. These can be put together to obtain a single linear map $V\to W$. Does that model your setup? What does motivate to pick two different bases of $W$?

Comment: This is it but there was not really a motivation why I picked two different bases of $W$. It just happened that it worked out (obversation that one can prove more then the subsequent statement under the yellow box with the yellow box), one of the purposes was to find a motivation.My questions to you are: What I said or what you summarized is possible? Did I prove this correctly? Is that the idea of **block matrices**? If so can this idea be expanded to not only changing the basis of $W$ but also of $V$ and also what would be the motivation of the notion of blockmatrices?

Comment: Block matrices correspond to split the bases, either of the domain or codomain or both, into smaller sets, hence splitting the matrix of any linear map to blocks. I.e. your construction is a special case when $C=C'$, and the matrix is split vertically to two blocks of equal size.